# How to change the background color of the focussed table row

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

So I've a method that focuses the table row based on the row index. However, the default background color of the focused row is grey, which is not easily visible. I want to change this color to steelblue. Please suggest how to do it. Below is my code for the method.

```
public static void focusTableRow(TableView table, int rowIndex){
    table.requestFocus();
    table.getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex);
    table.getFocusModel().focus(rowIndex); 
    table.scrollTo(rowIndex);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To style the rows, Add CSS in the external CSS file :

```
.table-row-cell:selected {

        -fx-background: steelblue;

}
```

**Update:**

Save the content of this style in a `rowStyles.css`. then you have to add the URL for the `rowStyles.css` style sheet to the scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("rowStyles.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I add this CSS style to the focussed row.